# Cannot get SymGetTypeInfo to work (error 1, Incorrect function)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, dbghelp

**TLDR**: Could someone explain how to correctly use the `SymGetTypeInfo`.

My goal is to get the type information for local variables (wherever `Rip`/`Eip` happens to be).

According to the documentation, I need to call the `SymSetContext` with the `IMAGEHLP_STACK_FRAME` structure filled with appropriate values. I got this part working as when I call `SymEnumSymbols` (setting the `BaseOfDll` parameter to `0` as the doc says to do when setting context), I do in fact only get the local variables.

**HOWEVER**:

When inside the enumerate symbols callback, I try to call `SymGetTypeInfo`, something like this:

```cpp
static BOOL s_enum_symbols_callback(
    PSYMBOL_INFO pSymInfo,
    ULONG SymbolSize,
    PVOID UserContext) {
    // ...

    HANDLE hProcess = /*Defined elsewhere*/;
    wchar_t *buffer = (wchar_t *)allocate_symname_memory();

    SymGetTypeInfo(hProcess, pSymInfo->ModBase, pSymInfo->TypeIndex, TI_GET_SYMNAME, &buffer);
}
```

`SymGetTypeInfo` fails with error 1 ("Incorrect function").

Ok so now I am troubleshooting to figure out why this might happen. My first theory is that this may have something to do with setting the context, so I remove the `SymSetContext` and enumerate again. This time (I obviously get all the symbols), and I get the same problem except for a *few* types, notably: I am able to get the type of `__scrt_current_native_startup_state`  (which is `__scrt_native_startup_state`).

Ok so maybe... the problem is that I am calling SymGetTypeInfo inside a Sym* callback function?? (doubt it though). Anyway, I put the theory to the test, and enumerate just the symbols which I have defined globally:

```cpp
wchar_t global_variable = 12;
int global_variable0 = 12;
float global_variable1 = 12.0f;
int global_variable2 = 12;
```

Once again, not setting the context, I enumerate the symbols and note the `TypeIndex` value for each so that once outside of the enumerate symbols function, I call `SymGetTypeInfo` like this:

```c
SymGetTypeInfo(hProcess, process_pdb_base, type_index, TI_GET_SYMNAME, &buffer);
```

(`process_pdb_base` is returned from `SymModuleLoad64`).

And I get the **SAME** problem.

Maybe I am completely misunderstanding what the `TypeIndex` really is? (although it is consistent for different variables with the same type), or maybe it's only for user-defined types??

So yeah I am lost and tired, please help internet.

Answer (score 1):

Alright guys, I think I figured it out and it's all thanks to [this marvelous article](http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/dbghelptypeinfo.html) written in 2004, by Oleg Starodumov!

And one of my theories wasn't completely wrong - I did indeed misunderstand what the Debug Help (well actually, the entire Win32 API!) library refers to, when using the word "type". As the article wonderfully puts it: "The type of an object defines the set of properties supported by the object, and the set of possible relationships between the object and other objects."

So really, the `SymGetTypeInfo` functions, is just used to query information about any symbol. Now there are indeed different categories of symbols, which are encapsulated by the `SymTagEnum` enumerator type which is defined in `DbgHelp.h` **IF** you have `_NO_CVCONST_H` defined with `#define` (**NOTE**: You use this if you don't have access to `cvconst.h` which was my case).

Because this article is so great and I don't want to spoil it for anyone, I will quickly resume what I needed to do to fix my issue, instead of trying to explain querying the C/C++ "type" information (not Win32 "type") of a variable.

The first thing I needed to do, was get the tag of the symbol which represented the C/C++ "type" of the local variable symbol (which is indeed stored in `TypeIndex`). Next, I needed the code to act accordingly for each different possible tag. In my case, because this was what was called a `BaseType`, I needed to query what `BaseType` the type symbol was. With this:

```c
SymGetTypeInfo(hProcess, pSymInfo->ModBase, pSymInfo->TypeIndex, TI_GET_BASETYPE, &type);
```

Now, each base type has a corresponding enum constant associated with it. The enum looks like this:

```c
enum BasicType
{
    btNoType = 0,
    btVoid = 1,
    btChar = 2,
    btWChar = 3,
    btInt = 6,
    btUInt = 7,
    btFloat = 8,
    btBCD = 9,
    btBool = 10,
    btLong = 13,
    btULong = 14,
    btCurrency = 25,
    btDate = 26,
    btVariant = 27,
    btComplex = 28,
    btBit = 29,
    btBSTR = 30,
    btHresult = 31
};
```

And lo and behold, the base type did in fact correspond with the types of my local variables!

**NOTE**
I couldn't find this enum in my system (most likely because I didn't have the Debugger Interface Access SDK), so to get it, I simply copied the `TypeInfoStructs.h` file located in [another link](http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/typeinfodump.html) provided by Oleg Starodumov.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.